# How can I do b * 2^a in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

I started to learn vhdl last weeks. And I don't understand writing code of B * 2^A. In this case, B being a 2's complement integer of 3-bit signal, and A being a 2-bit signal representing an unsigned binary integer, the result of this multiplication will be a 6-bit signal represented in 2's
complement.

I tried to use arithmetic binary shift to the left because I am trying to keep the sing of B when performing this operation.

My code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mult_2 is
 Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
 b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
 m_o : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0));
end mult_2;

architecture mult_2_arch of mult_2 is
begin

 m_o <= b sla (2 * a);

end mult_2_arch;
```

Comment: *B * 2^A.*  There's no indication of the language of this notation. What does ^ mean? It's not a VHDL delimiter.

Comment: Because you're using sla we can assume you're using -2008. Adding another assumption that the ^ operator in your original expression in another language stands for XOR, with `use ieee.numeric_std.all;` as an additional use clause then `m_o <= std_logic_vector(signed(b) sla to_integer("10" xor unsigned (a)));` It doesn't appear sla can be used as a synonym for * here when unsigned a can have values of 1 and 3.

Comment: in VHDL,exponentiation is `**` so `B * 2**A;` (Also, use the correct datatypes from numeric_std)

Comment: @user16145658 it is meaning power of 2. I didn't know how can I put A to top of the 2 in stackoverflow. Therefore I used 2^A.

Comment: [m_o needs to be lengthened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ShaZ.jpg) for SLA. Shifting 8 left is still not the equivalent of multiplying by 8 (a shift of 3).  You can simply shift left (the RESIZE sign extends) by a with the original m_o declaration. `m_o <= std_logic_vector (RESIZE(signed(b),m_o'length) sla to_integer(unsigned(a)));`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using VHDL-2008. The following:

```vhdl
m_o <= b sla (2 * a);
```

does not do what you think. First, `sla` returns a vector with same length as `b`, that is, 3 bits not 6. Second, you are left-shifting by `2*a` positions, which is different from multiplying by `2**a` (`2` at the `a`). What you should do is:

- Sign-extend `b` to 6 bits,
- Left-shift the result by `a` positions.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
m_o <= std_logic_vector(resize(u_signed(b), 6) sla to_integer(u_unsigned(a)));
```